# Why can't Oracle Linux automatically detect CPUs with AVX?

Tags: linux, x86, avx, avx2, oraclelinux

I'm facing an issue with my Oracle Linux; it doesn't show AVX support in the `/proc/cpuinfo | grep -i avx` output. However, when used with another operating system like CentOS 7, AVX support is detected.

I have also tried upgrading the kernel for Oracle Linux, but it seems infeasible. I wonder if there's any way for Oracle Linux to recognize CPUs with AVX support.

Comment: Are you running both OSes in VMs configured the same way?  If not, it might be that the VM isn't passing through AVX.  What kernel version are you using?  Have you tried running a `cpuid` tool that doesn't depend on the kernel's `/proc/cpuinfo` to see if it reports CPU support for AVX which your kernel chooses not to use?  That would be a red flag it was the kernel's fault, but I'd expect only very old kernels would be configured without AVX, if that was ever optional, or ancient to predate AVX support being added at all, some time before 2010 when AVX hardware first came out.

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes, Both operating systems are running on the same VMESXi, and the kernel I am using is "5.15.0-200.131.27.1.el8uek.x86_64" (this kernel has been upgraded). The OS with AVX support is using kernel version "3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64". I also used lscpu to check, but there is still no indication of AVX support. The CPU I am using is "Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6248 CPU @ 2.50GHz". I suspect that there might be an issue with Oracle's OS. I have read this article: https://linux.oracle.com/errata/ELSA-2023-1569.html. However, after updating and restarting the OS, there is still no change.

Comment: It works for me, with `5.4.17-2136.325.5.1.el8uek.x86_64`, also running on VMware ESXi.

Comment: `lscpu` opens `/proc/cpuinfo`; I wouldn't trust it to check the actual CPU feature bits reported by the `cpuid` instruction, instead of relying on what the kernel detected (which won't include AVX if it's not looking for it).

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes, I also don't have much confidence in it. But the crucial issue is that I cannot run MongoDB 5.0+ on it. According to my research, the operating system currently does not support AVX. I have tested it with CentOS 8, and it works perfectly, resembling Oracle Linux 8. So, is there something crazy happening with Red Hat's kernels?

Comment: Hi @pmdba, What do you need to do to downgrade to that kernel? Or did you install another OS that already uses that kernel?

Comment: I don't think downgrading is possible. You'd have to reinstall from scratch from an older distribution media.

Comment: Thanks @pmdba, I think I've successfully configured `5.15.0-200.131.27.1.el8uek.x86_64`. To make it work properly, I need to use vCenter and enable `VMware EVC`. However, I had to downgrade the CPU mode from `Cascade Lake` to `Sandy Bridge` lol :))).